# Create link on imported external text files into flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtf

When I import an external text file with .rtf format into flash a part of text becomes abnormal like this:

[image]

The second problem is that I don't know how to convert a word or a sentence in this text to a link, when it is loaded in flash.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: I know nothing about ActionScript, but what you're seeing is the actual Rich Text Format.  If you save a file from Wordpad as a .rtf file and open it up in Notepad, you'll see the same thing.  It looks as if the textbox you're loading the .rtf file into isn't equipped to interpret Rich Text Format and display it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, At first - only in html text in Flash is posible to use text as link, 
try to use html text format instead .rtf, because as I know there are not any tools to convert .rtf to html in AS3. Also you can use pdf format in AIR applications.